# Why RDF4J won't work in Bluemix Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, rdf4j

RDF4J is an apache open source graph db that i use often on my PC.
It comes with 2 webApp : **RDF4J-server** and **RDF4J-workbench** (a user interface)
On my PC i push the 2 wars in the same Tomcat and everything is ok.
I begin an experiment to **push these apps in the Bluemix Cloud** (which is a cloud foundry)
The java-tomcat boilerplate wants a single War in order to associate it with the URL of the new container, so i **create 2 separate apps** in 2 java containers :
  1 for RDF4J-Server,
  1 for RDF4J-WB.
Both apps are running and i can access to default pages.
In WB, the form 'connect to server' allows you to give the URL of the server you want to work with.
I enter the URL *https://rdf4jmyserver.mybluemix.net*. WB finds the server but loops on the form, unable to open a db.

I suppose first that a split in 2 containers can be an issue, but i do the following test :
-run RD4J workbench in a **local Tomcat** on my machine
-connect to the rdf4Jmyserver  **on the cloud**
-> Everything is ok !
So the pb is not to run in 2 separate places.

I investigate a bit more, dowload the source code (thanks open source) and recompile with more and more debug traces .

After a long day, i found the bug in the Workbench code, despite the fact this code is as old as the previous version Sesame: Nobody catch it .

Philosophy for today :
**Bluemix works well**, but pushing an app in the cloud can reveal old weakness !

I will give the patch in a next post.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation : 
When the selected server by workbench is not the default one ( which is supposed to be on the same root url ), the program establish a new cookie to keep trace of the new choice.

The wrong code is here , in *CookieHandler.java* :

```
private void initCookie(final Cookie cookie, final HttpServletRequest req) {
    final String context = req.getContextPath();
     cookie.setPath(null == context ? "/" : context);
    }
}
```

The url is something like *https://rdf4j-mywb.mybluemix.net*
So, when there is no context for the cookie, the software wants to add a /  .
But **this code is false**.

Going back to the java API, one can see :

*public java.lang.String getContextPath()*

*Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request.*
*The context path always comes first in a request URI.*
*The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character.*
**For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "".**
*The container does not decode this string.*

So this old buried bug can be fixed by :

```
// cookie.setPath(null == context ? "/" : context);
cookie.setPath(context.isEmpty()? "/" : context);
```

And now, Workbench works well on Bluemix !

HTH

PS: as rdf4Jserver runs also in a cloud container, datas on disk can disappear when container is reset. Another job has to be done : using an objectstore service in Bluemix. ( another day)